# Symfony Clearning Cache RunTimeException

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am trying to clear cache in the production environment on my distant server, when i enter the command:

```
   php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I get the following error:

```
   [RuntimeException]
   Unable to write in the "C:/wamp2/www/Symfony/app/cache/prod" directory
```

Why is it looking for the file in my local directory structure?

**Note:**

The command

```
       php app/console cache:clear
```

Works fine. Is there an intermediary cache that i have to clear?

And another Question, How do i clear the log files? Because it is now a massive 250Mb file, i would like to lighten my project. Can i just empty the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can remove your log files or better: create a task to gzip them. Its up to you.

And for clear your cache, you are doing it right. Maybe your user doesn't have permission to remove them.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/*
sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs/*
```

or

See the oficial documentation to set the right permission to your `cache` and `log` dirs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup